# Cross browser voice in speechSynthesis

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to convert a text to speech using [SpeechSynthesisUtterance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance). The [example](https://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speak-easy-synthesis/) provided in the MDN works just fine with a single browser, but `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` returns a different number of voices in each browser and OS. (22 in windows chrome, 3 in firefox chrome, 40+ in ubuntu chrome, 100+ in ios Safari).

I wanted to use the voice `Tessa en-ZA`, but seems it is only available in safari.
Is there a cross-browser solution for this, so that the voice is the same in all browsers (Like loading a voice URI on every browser)?

Comment: Cross-browser, within the same OS, yes, probably, eg, Microsoft David / Zira (since those are provided by the OS), but not cross-OS, I think

Comment: should leave it up to the user to choose the voice, that's why there's an api for it, if you personally prefer Tessa, then use Safari, I'm on linux, chrome I have like 10 voices, all sound like C-3PO.

Comment: You could look at responsive voice which seems to give the same voice cross-browser.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Asking the user to set voice each time won't be a good idea. I could save the voice user selected, but that value won't be useful if the same user used another browser next time. So I'm just trying to find a way to play the same sound to all the users in the app, irrespective of browser/OS.